# Basic addition for form security gives wrong answer PHP

Tags: php, forms

I have a basic math question that the user has to answer before they can send an email:

```
$first_num = rand(1, 4);
$second_num = rand(1, 4);

$send = @$_POST['send'];
if($send){

    //The user's answer from the input box
    $answer = @$_POST["answer"];

    if($answer == $first_num + $second_num) {
        //Do stuff
    }
    else {
        $error_message = "You answered the question wrong!";
    }
}
```

I answer the question correctly (unless my first grade math is off!) yet it says I have the question wrong. I am not sure what the issue is but I imagine it is something to do with the fact that php executes immediately when the page is loaded and so new numbers are generated as soon as the user presses the submit button? Or am I way off? If that is the case, what can be done to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are setting your values every time your script is called. So when you post your form, two new values are set and they are likely not the same values as when you called the script the first time to show the form.

You should store your variables in a session and retrieve these values when you process your post request.

Something like:

```
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['numbers']))
{
  $_SESSION['numbers']['first'] = rand(1, 4);
  $_SESSION['numbers']['second'] = rand(1, 4);
}

...

   if ($answer == $_SESSION['numbers']['first'] + $_SESSION['numbers']['second']) {
     //Do stuff

     /**
       unset the variables after successfully processing the form so that
       you will get new ones next time you open the form
      */
     unset($_SESSION['numbers']);

   ...
```

Note that you will need to use the session variables everywhere where you are using your own variables right now.

Comment: Thanks for the response and explanation, I am doing as you demonstrated but the answer to the sum of the two numbers is always 8 now. Any other number does not work, even if it is the correct sum of the two random numbers.

Comment: @Reece55 Make sure you use the session variables everywhere, also when you generate the form. And your session is unique to you but if you would like different values while browsing yourself, you should unset the `$_SESSION['numbers']` variable after a successful form post. That way, next time when you show the form, two new values will be generated and stored in the session.

Answer (score 0):

You should include the two numbers as hidden form inputs in your HTML, and then do the math with the entries in your $_POST array.

Make your code start like this instead:

```
$first_num = $_POST["first_num"];
$second_num = $_POST["second_num"];
```

Comment: Putting the values in your form makes your form security trivially easy to crack.

Comment: Agreed, if someone were to target this specific website for attack. I think most such attacks would be directed at frameworks with large install bases like Wordpress, or a large government's or multinational's website. I'm imagining this code will end up on an SMB website alongside a "contact us" page so I mentioned the easiest approach.